# Enhanced Ecommerce Get Checkout Abandonment

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I've implemented Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce on my site. However I cannot track checkout abandonment.

I've implemented it this way.

- Every time a customer checkout an order (eg. masterpass or visa), I fire this code before redirecting to their page (if the user clicks masterpass or visa payment)

> ```
> ga('ec:addProduct', {               // Provide product details in an productFieldObject.
>   'id': 'P12345',                   // Product ID (string).
>   'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt', // Product name (string).
>   'category': 'Apparel',            // Product category (string).
>   'brand': 'Google',                // Product brand (string).
>   'variant': 'black',               // Product variant (string).
>   'price': '29.20',                 // Product price (currency).
>   'quantity': 1                     // Product quantity (number).
> });
> ```
>
> ga('ec:setAction','checkout', {
>       'step': 1,
>       'option': 'Visa' });

I can track sessions with checkout however my checkout abandonment is stuck at 0, even if I don't attempt to checkout.

Do you guys have any knowledge about this?

Answer (score 1):

---

Hi,

The code as it is would be incomplete, you need to fire a hit in order to send all that information either with a pageview or an event.

When in a session there is no cart activity the checkout abandonment is 0% (since no one started a checkout process)